# Find a subset such that there is a cts function whose image is {0,1}

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Want to find a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that there exists a cts function $f$ on the set such that the image $f(X) = \{0,1\}$, that is takes both values 0 and 1.

This is part of a larger question (IVT in higher dimensions) but just wanted to help understand this portion. Should be the case that some subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ have such a function while others don't.

For a subset that doesn't, I came up with the set that consists only of the zero vector, ${(0,0,0)}$.

I might be overthinking it but struggling to come up with one since the function that exists needs to be continuous (otherwise I'd just do a piece wise function).

Appreciate any tips

Comment: Hint: the continuous image of a connected set is connected. So $X$ must be ....

Comment: So we didn't cover connectedness in the course that I'm taking but I'm aware of the notion. But I'm guessing $X$ must be disconnected (say union of two disjoint nonempty sets?) and can find a function that works with said $X$.

Comment: Exactly - and check that the thing you find (use the simplest possible function) is continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: A crucial hypothesis in IVT is connectedness. Can you think of such a function on a disconnected domain?